# Laravel and Kohana on Openshift?

Tags: git, laravel, kohana, openshift, cloud-hosting

I would like to `git push` two projects (using the [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/) frameworks) to [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/). Does Openshift support these frameworks? I did not see these frameworks in any of Openshift's cartridges (I only saw CakePHP and CodeIgniter). Is there a way to get these frameworks working on Openshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the answer here: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/kohana-and-laravel-on-openshift

**Excerpt from the Openshift resource**:

With the Laravel quickstart on github, you should be able to do the following:
Create a php-5.3 application and attach mongodb to it:

```
rhc app create -a laravelapp php-5.3 mongodb-2.2
```

Add this upstream laravelapp repo:

```
cd laravelapp
git remote add upstream -m master https://github.com/stikmanw/openshift-laravel-mongo
git pull -s recursive -X theirs upstream master
```

Then push the repo upstream:

```
git push
```

Note that similar steps can be done for any github repo that matches the directory structure of the cartridge you're using. But the github README usually contains these steps specifically (just like mediawiki-example: https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/mediawiki-example)

With Kohana, you should be able to use any cartridge you want. With the php-5.3 cartridge, you can try suggestions here: [Installing Kohana on OpenShift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950525/installing-kohana-on-openshift)

E.g., place all kohana files into your repo/php/ directory, then do a git add/commit/push. That's because repo/php/ is considered your application's webroot dir.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.