# Installing Kohana on OpenShift?

Tags: php, mysql, git, kohana-3, openshift

How do I [install Kohana v3.3.1](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/install) on Openshift? Do I create the PHP 5.3 cartridge and put the kohana files inside the php directory? Or do I create a Zend Server 5.6? I would like to use MySQL as well.

Kohana v3.3.1 requires **PHP 5.3.3** or higher to work. I just created a PHP 5.3 Cartridge and `git clone` it to my harddrive and here is the file structure:

```
C:\mysite>ls -a
.  ..  .git  .openshift  README.md  deplist.txt  libs  misc  php

C:\mysite>
```

Inside the php directory

```
C:\mysite\php>ls -a
.  ..  health_check.php  index.php

C:\mysite\php>
```

When I edited `php\index.php` to `echo "Hello World"` I was able to see Hello World in my browser at my Openshift address `http://xxxx-xxxx.rhcloud.com/`

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT 1**

I listed the cartridges and discovered `Do-it-Yourself 0.1`

```
rhc cartridge list
```

Is this [Do-it-Yourself 0.1](https://www.openshift.com/wiki/introduction-to-cartridge-building) cartridge building what I need to do to get Kohana working on Openshift?

Comment: You should be able to use the php-5.3 cartridge and place all kohana files into your repo/php/ directory, then do a git add/commit/push.  I gave that a shot and noticed one error about the system directory:  "The configured system directory does not exist or does not contain required files." but I'm assuming that's because the system directory is empty?

Comment: +1 Thank you for your reply. When you installed Kohana on Openshift, did all of the checks return green?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would drop your code inside the basic `php-5.3` application skeleton, and go from there.

You can add `mysql` to any application by listing it as a dependency during your `rhc app create` step, or by typing `rhc cartridge add mysql` from within your local project repo folder.

Once you get everything working, I would consider publishing the resulting repo to GitHub.  This should allow others to spin up your openshift-compatible copy of Kohana by running:

```
rhc app create kohana php-5.3 mysql --from-code=http://github.com/YOUR_ACCOUNT/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.git
```

(with `YOUR_ACCOUNT` and `YOUR_PROJECT_NAME` substituted into the above command)

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for recommending that I publish to GitHub. Thanks for the code snippet!! Will do.